# Why can't I deploy tensorflow model on cloud run? It always returns service unavailable

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy my tensorflow model so that it can be accessed by my android app. I'm using cloud run by following the documentation from here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python?authuser=2
I've tried deploying simple flask python code from that tutorial and succeeded in returning a jsonified response that responds to the endpoint modification. It works perfectly but however when I import tensorflow inside the python code, it just won't work. It says service is unavailable. I can't figure out what's wrong.

So I already have the model as `model.h5` in the root folder. This is how the directory looks like:

[image]

Here is what's happening

[image]

Can anyone please explain what's going on here? Here is my `main.py`

```
import os

from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np

model = load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})

def test(string):
    labelOutput= {1: 'B-DESC',
                  2: 'B-LOCATION',
                  3: 'I-LOCATION',
                  4: 'I-DESC',
                  5: 'B-WEAPON',
                  6: 'B-PERSON',
                  7: 'I-PERSON',
                  8: 'I-WEAPON',
                  0: 'O'}
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        pred = model.predict(string)[i]
        labelIndex = np.argmax(pred)
        result += ('{:20} {}\n'.format(string[i], labelOutput.get(labelIndex)))
    return result

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/ner")
def hello_world():
    string_input = request.args.get('input')
    hasil = test(string_input)
    return jsonify({"prediction":hasil})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install tensorflow
RUN pip install tensorflow-hub

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

And this is my `.dockerignore`:

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
model.h5
```

The model is contained within this drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KLpXtYMzILeVNAMcVIoMCKVTqfx2H8nn?usp=sharing

Any answer here would be greatly appreciated... I'm stuck and can't figure out how to proceed with this..

Comment: It's very likely you're doing something wrong. Please search Tensorflow serving on Cloud Run and you'll get some blogs/articles. You should also check your logs to see what the error is and you should also try to see if it works locally first https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local

Comment: Firstly, test you container locally to be sure that is work correctly out of cloud run runtime. Then, you can rely on 2 articles that I wrote, one [with embedded model](https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1), the other with [dynamic model loading](https://medium.com/google-cloud/on-demand-small-batch-predictions-with-cloud-run-and-embedded-tf-469242d66c3b), and, in both case, with online prediction

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, when you create or run a container using docker create or docker run, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world

Please add to your Dockerfile `EXPOSE 8080`

2. Secondly, your model is kinda big, so make sure you set an increased memory on Cloud Run instances, like 4GB or even higher.
3. Other than that, check the Logs of the service, for any issues there could be a python stacktrace. I have a 95% similar codebase to yours and mostly the problem is memory and small pieces, paths. Test with serving a basic `hello word` and work out from there.